# how can i make two fileds in one row

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

i have written this code and i am not able to keep the data array of two different identiy type into one row as a field and i have used this code

```
import React from 'react'
import {Form,Field,ErrorMessage,Formik} from 'formik'
import * as yup from 'yup'

const schema=yup.object().shape({
    cmt:yup.string().min(4,'minimun 4 words').required('comment is reqired'),
    name:yup.string().required('Name is reqired'),
    email:yup.string().required('Email is reqired'),
    website:yup.string().required('Enter website url or name'),
})

function ReplyForm() {
    const data=[
        {type:'text',placeholder:'Write a comment',identiy:'cmt'},
        {type:'text',placeholder:'Name',identiy:'name'},
        {type:'email',placeholder:'Email',identiy:'email'},
        {type:'text',placeholder:'Website',identiy:'website'},
    ]
  return (
    <div className='w-full flex justify-center'>
        <div className='w-10/12 bg-blue-200'>
            <Formik
            initialValues={{
                cmt:'',
                name:'',
                email:'',
                website:'',
            }}
            validationSchema={schema}
            onSubmit={(values)=>{
                console.log(values)
            }}
            >
                {({handlesubmit})=>{
                    return <Form onSubmit={handlesubmit}>
                        <div className='w-3/5'>
                            {data.map((val,i)=>{
                                
                                    if ((val.identiy==='name')||(val.identiy==='email')){
                                       return <div key={i} className='flex justify-between'>
                                            <Field type={val.type} name={val.identiy} placeholder={val.placeholder} className='w-1/2'/>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        return <div key={i}>
                                        <Field type={val.type} name={val.identiy} placeholder={val.placeholder}/>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                            })}
                        </div>
                    </Form>
                }}
            </Formik>
            
        </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default ReplyForm
```

and its output is something like this
[image: this is the output]

but actually I want something like this where name and email will be in one same row just like this
[image: required output]

just help me to make those two in one row

Comment: Can you share any online playground with the code, so that I can reproduce the error in it and resolve the issue. I had tried it but unable to do it.

Comment: Should "fileds" be changed to "fields"?

Answer (score 0):

Flex doesn't work like that. U need to wrap name and email inside a flex to make them in a row.
I think you should make the parent node have flex-wrap, and the children node have width 100%, for name and email width 50% (if flex have gap or something make it stretch to next line, decrease width with calc or anyway).
There is an example

```css
.container{
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}
.item{
  width: 100%;
  background: #afc;
  height: 50px;
}
.item:nth-child(2),
.item:nth-child(3){
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout).

Code:

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-6 sm:grid-cols-2 p-20">
    <div class="sm:col-span-2">
        <div class="w-full h-28 bg-red-500 rounded-md text-white text-2xl text-center p-10 font-mono">Large 1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="w-full h-14 bg-red-500 rounded-md text-white text-2xl text-center p-3 font-mono">Half</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="w-full h-14 bg-red-500 rounded-md text-white text-2xl text-center p-3 font-mono">Half</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sm:col-span-2">
        <div class="w-full h-14 bg-red-500 rounded-md text-white text-2xl text-center p-3 font-mono">Middle</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image: preview]

Explanation:

[`grid`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display#grid) to define your `grid`.  [`grid-cols-1`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns#basic-usage) to create a grid with 1 equally sized column for mobile devices.

[`gap-6`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gap#basic-usage) to change the space between both rows and columns in the grid.
[`sm:grid-cols-2`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns#basic-usage) is to create a grid with 2 equally sized columns for `640px` and wider screens.

And for those elements that you want to be on the same line (like "comment" and "website") use [`sm:col-span-2`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-column#spanning-columns) to let them take up the whole horizontal space on `640px` and wider screens.

See [playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/nQOcQmWZJV).